# Modify NTEventlogFile OverwritePolicy/Retention Cycle by WMI

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I‘m trying to set via VBS the `Win32_NTEventlogFile` to keep entries for 10 days. I know I need an elevated shell to modify the security log. I’ve used the samples from Microsoft with this code

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Security)}!\\" & _
        strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colLogFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile " _
        & "Where LogFileName='Security'")
For Each objLogFile in colLogFiles
    objLogfile.MaxFileSize = (50*1024)
    objLogFile.OverwriteOutDated=10
    objLogFile.OverwritePolicy=OutDated
    objLogFile.Put_(&H20000)
Next
```

This works for changing the maximum file size, but it does not work for setting the retention cycle.

When I query OverwriteOutDated again after changing it it says ‚0‘ in WMI. When I access it with powershell `PS Get-Eventlog -List`

It reports

```
Retain: -1
OverflowAction: DoNotOverwrite
```

But when I change it via powershell with

```
Limit-EventLog -LogName Security -RetentionDays 10 -OverflowAction OverwriteOlder
```

It works

```
Retain: 10
OverflowAction: OverwriteOlder
```

There is no error in the WMI call reported. I just seems to mess up the entry. Am I forgetting something when trying to change the retention cycle via WMI?

Comment: If it works via PowerShell why bother with VBScript.

Comment: Cause I‘ve an existing VBS software, which needs to be modified in this regard. And calling a powershell script from vbs is possible but I would prefer to not introduce another api if the other should support it.

Comment: That's a fair enough reason, will say that WMI is its own thing it's an extension of the existing Windows APIs it is not "native" to VBScript.

Comment: According to the [WMI Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394225(v=vs.85)) the `OverWritePolicy` property is `read-only`. I cannot see an issue with the code other than setting this value which might cause unexpected results, maybe just drop that one line and see if that fixes the issue.